# Upgrading to texlive 2011

Tags: texlive, updating

I can't seem to upgrade to TL2011 somehow:

```
root@dell:/usr/local/texlive/2011# ./update-tlmgr-latest.sh -- --upgrade
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater...............................................................................................................................................................................
./runme.sh: updating in /usr/local/texlive/2011...
./runme.sh: tlmgr version says this is TeX Live 2011
./runme.sh: proceeding with tlmgr update.
D:tlmgr:main: ::tldownload_server defined
D:Using system wget (tested).
D:Using shipped /usr/local/texlive/2011/tlpkg/installer/xz/xzdec.i386-linux for xzdec (tested).
D:Using shipped /usr/local/texlive/2011/tlpkg/installer/xz/xz.i386-linux for xz (not tested).
./runme.sh: done.
root@dell:/usr/local/texlive/2011# echo $PATH
/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
root@dell:/usr/local/texlive/2011# tlmgr update  --self --all
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates available
```

I'm following the instructions on this page: http://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html
I've tried other mirrors, but I don't get any updates. I am missing something?

Comment: It's OK. No updates available by now.

Comment: I mean I'm upgrading from 2010 following the instructions. So I copied the `2010` directory to `2011` and then ran these commands, but it won't upgrade anything.

Comment: I'm following these instructions: http://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html

Comment: Do a fresh install.

Comment: Does that mean these instructions are wrong?

Comment: I can't say, I've never tried them. A fresh install might be longer, but should run without problems.

Comment: There are no updates available by now. The first step is to make TeXLive2011 in the current state available. That has been successfully upgraded to your system. Then it always takes some days until all updated packages until the last freeze are available for an update. I suppose it should be possible at the begin of next week.

Comment: @egreg The instructions worked fine for everyone who tested them so far. Admittedly, "everyone who tested" means only 2-3 persons currently... But if doesn't make sense to quit using he upgrade instruction without any serious indication of a problem with them.

Comment: Alright, since my connection is not much of a problem, I did a fresh install :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your installation is working fine. If the update didn't work, you wouldn't get the `no updates available` message (which actually means what it says) but instead you would have an error message like:

```
The supported release as specified by the repository (2011)
does not match the release version of the installation (2010), bailing out.
```

As the comments say, just way a few days for updates to appear. Karl re-enabled them for tonight, so if everything's fine, you should start seeing updates in a few days.